# How to open PDF file with Pdf.js viewer after some PHP codes executing? (without ?file=URL_PDF)

Tags: javascript, php, .htaccess, pdf, pdf.js

I don't know my question title is enough good or not.

I am tried to build pdf viewer in my website with PDf.js. I know, normally it's simple as:
http://example.com/pdfjs/web/viewer.html?file=PDF_URL

But my claim is - Pdf url dont show in the address bar.
I was created view.php from viewer.html codes. And I want like this:
http://example.com/pdfjs/web/view.php?file=1

So in my php page I check database and fetch fileurl from ID=1.

and finally I want to set Pdf.js viewer for to open my pdf from Fileurl.
But I cant. I am lost much time for this, googling for hours, but I cant unfortunately.

What can I do? Or what can I do for getting like this result? Or with .htaccess is it like this possible?
(sorry for my low quality English)

```php
<?php
// my view.php

if(isset($_GET['file'])){
  $file = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, @$_GET['file']);
}else{
  $file="";
}

if(is_numeric($file) AND $file!=""){
  $query = mysqli_query($db, "select * FROM pdf_files WHERE id='$file' ");
     if(mysqli_num_rows($query) == 1){
        $result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sorgu);
        $filepath = $result['filepath'];
}

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <link rel="resource" type="application/l10n" href="locale/locale.properties">
  <script src="../build/pdf.js"></script>
  <script src="viewer.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <!--Other Pdf.js viewer.html codes-->
</body>
</html>
```

Now when I am going to http://example.com/pdfjs/web/view.php?file=1 ,

PdfJS giving error like this:
Message: Missing PDF "http://example.com/pdfjs/web/1".

Comment: `$filepath = $result['filepath'];` - great, so now you (probably) have the path to a PDF file in this variable `$filepath`. And now where exactly are you actually _doing_ anything with that value …?

Comment: Now I want to do 'something' which load my pdf file from ```$filepath``` . But I dont know what is 'something' and how I do it. I read from some pdfjs docs and issues, so I decide I can do it with some javascript codes. But I dont know more.